# Trace / track registry and network events on Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, monitoring

Is there a way to trace registry and network events on Windows 7? I already use WMI `Win32_ModuleLoadTrace` events for files and processes.

I know that I can do it by using a MiniFilter driver but I would like to stay in user mode. I also need the process ID for a given event.

Comment: Take a look @ ETW: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx (Search here for [ETW])

Comment: The problem with ETW is that you don't have real-time access to the full key names on each event.  You usually have to wait for later events to discover the key names of earlier events.  See [ETW - Registry monitoring](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff07fc25-31e3-4b6f-810e-7a1ee458084b/etw-registry-monitoring).

Comment: That is okey! Any idea which ETW provider can be used to fetch DNS queries & answers?